# Can I use Web APIs in chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, web-worker, google-chrome-os

I want to use web workers in a chrome app I plan on creating. But not certain if I can use all web apis in chrome app (or in this case web workers).

So my questions is: **Can I use all web apis that the chrome browser can use in chrome apps**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So I found the answer to it just a few minutes after posting this question**

According to the [Web API section](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_other) in the chrome apps documentation:

> In addition to the chrome.* APIs, extensions can use all the APIs that the browser provides to web pages and apps. If the browser doesn't support an API you want to use, you can bundle additional API libraries into your extension.

Don't worry about the term 'extension' in the quote above, it seems the documentation was copied from the extensions' web api section.